# If $AA^* $ and $BB^*$ are unitarily similar Can we prove that $A $ and $B$ are unitarily similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in M_n$ and $AA^* $ and $BB^*$ are unitarily similar.

Can we prove that $A $ and $B$ are unitarily similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is false in general. Consider $A=I_n$  and $B=-I_n$. Since only $I_n$  is unitarily equivalent to $A$, $A$ and $B$ are not unitarily equivalent, but $AA^\ast = BB^\ast$.